# How many integers not divisible by $7$ are there between $[1-8888]$ using the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, contest-math

> How many integers not divisible by $7$ are there between $[1-8888]$ using the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.For example $49$ cannot be used because of $9$.

$\mathbf{\text{My attempt:}}$ I said that if we cannot use $9$, then we can think the question like it was written in base $9$. Then, if I subtract the number of integers divisible by $7$ from the total, we can reach the answer.

Total number of integers : $(8888)_9 - (1)_9=(8887)_9=6559$

The number of integers divisible by $7$: $$\frac{(8887)_9 - (7)_9}{(7)_9}+(1)_9 = (1251)_9=937$$

So my answer is $6559-937=5622$

Am I correct? If not, can you correct me or give another approach?

$\mathbf{\text{EDIT:}}$ I realize that i made a mistake in calculating the numbers of integers in $[1-8888]$ that do not contain integer $9$. The right calculation : $$\frac{(8888)_9 - (1)_9}{(1)_9} + (1)_9 =6560 $$

Now , the answer is $6560 -937 =5623$ , but it still contradict with the answer given by @HennoBrandsma , so i want to understand what my mistake is.

Comment: I think base 9 is irrelevant. I think the question asks all non-multiples of $7$ that do not contain the digit $9$ (in decimal). $49$ is out anyway because it *is* a multiple of $7$. It's also out because it contains a $9$.

Comment: The answer is 5624 BTW. By cheating.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma can you expalain why $5624$ instead of $5622$

Comment: no, it's just the answer. brute force.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma then , what is mistake in my solution

Comment: the base9 idea is irrelevant?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma if you want you can write your brute-force solution , i thought that it can be solved easily using base $9$.

Comment: If you want bold text, you can use put two asterisks before and after the text that will be bold like `**bold text**` to get **bold text**.

Comment: Does 8888 count as in the range ? (my solution assumes it is).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes , it is in the range

Answer (score 1):

```
count=0
for n in range(1,8889):
     if (n %7) != 0 and '9' not in str(n):
          count+=1
print(count)
```

Gives 5624, which I think answers to the interpretation.